# Why does this output 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 rather than the execute method's return calculations?

Tags: java, arrays, methods, switch-statement

I'm trying to have the main method print the returned results from the execute method's switch statement for every iteration of the arrays. However, the output is:

0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0

Could anyone advise why this might be?

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double[] leftVal = {100.0d, 25.0d, 225.0d, 11.0d};
        double[] rightVal = {50.0d, 92.0d, 17.0d, 3.0d};
        char[] opCodes = {'d', 'a', 's', 'm'};
        double[] results = new double[opCodes.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < opCodes.length; i++) {
            execute(opCodes[i], leftVal[i], rightVal[i]);
        }

        for (double currentResult : results) {
            System.out.println(currentResult);
        }
    }

    static double execute(char opCodes, double leftVal, double rightVal) {
        double result;
        switch (opCodes) {
            case 'a':
                result = leftVal + rightVal;
                break;
            case 's':
                result = leftVal - rightVal;
                break;
            case 'm':
                result = leftVal * rightVal;
                break;
            case 'd':
                result = rightVal != 0 ? leftVal / rightVal : 0.0d;
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Invalid opCode: " + opCodes);
                result = 0.0d;
                break;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are doing nothing with the return value of your `execute`  method .

Comment: You are not filling `results` anywhere. It remains filled with the default values.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing an assignment, you are not filling your `results` array.
Your are probably looking for this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < opCodes.length; i++) {
  results[i] = execute(opCodes[i], leftVal[i], rightVal[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I see is, that you dont use the return double

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double[] leftVal = {100.0d, 25.0d, 225.0d, 11.0d};
        double[] rightVal = {50.0d, 92.0d, 17.0d, 3.0d};
        char[] opCodes = {'d', 'a', 's', 'm'};
        double[] results = new double[opCodes.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < opCodes.length; i++) {
            results[i] = execute(opCodes[i], leftVal[i], rightVal[i]);
        }

        for (double currentResult : results) {
            System.out.println(currentResult);
        }
    }

    static double execute(char opCodes, double leftVal, double rightVal) {
        double result;
        switch (opCodes) {
            case 'a':
                result = leftVal + rightVal;
                break;
            case 's':
                result = leftVal - rightVal;
                break;
            case 'm':
                result = leftVal * rightVal;
                break;
            case 'd':
                result = rightVal != 0 ? leftVal / rightVal : 0.0d;
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Invalid opCode: " + opCodes);
                result = 0.0d;
                break;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

It should work like this, if your method works like it should

Answer (score 0):

Inside the for statement there is no assignment to fill the array with values.

```
for (int i = 0; i < opCodes.length; i++) {
        execute(opCodes[i], leftVal[i], rightVal[i]);
    }
```

In your execute method you return the double result.  Use that as an assignment to fill the results array.

```
for (int i = 0; i < opCodes.length; i++) {
        results[i] = execute(opCodes[i], leftVal[i], rightVal[i]);
    }
```